# SVN ssl connect error on Mac with svn: E175002: Unexpected HTTP status 500

Tags: macos, svn, ssl-certificate, redmine

I try to checkout SVN but I face with this issue

```
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://abc.xyz/svn/def'
svn: E175002: Unexpected HTTP status 500 'Internal Server Error' on '/svn/def'

svn: E175002: Additional errors:
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request on '/svn/def' failed: 500 Internal Server Error
```

Info:

- `https://abc.xyz/svn/def` is working well, I can connect by using web browser like safari/chrome. I also can checkout on other system like Ubuntu/Windows, but Mac.
- The problem here is about the SSL certificate because that server is certificate self-signed and it worked with `http` before, I supposed.
- That is an integrated SVN server with `Redmine`.
- I've tried with `svn co https://abc.xyz/svn/def --non-interactive --trust-server-cert` but it wont work on my case.

Comment: Do you have access to server logs? They should contain more details about this error. Are you using the same SVN versions on all those systems?

Comment: I will try to post server log later. But I use same version with across platform. I try with Ubuntu an TortoiseSVN(1.8) and they all work

Comment: if you're connecting to an internal domain, make sure you try the full domain e.g. https://sub.domain.tld and not just https://sub. It addressed the SSL handshake issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem here is about the SSL certificate because that server is certificate self-signed

In any case, for such certs you must at least once

`svn co https://abc.xyz/svn/def --non-interactive --trust-server-cert`

or manipulate by `ssl-trust-default-ca`, `ssl-authority-files` from SVN's servers file

Comment: I've tried. I saw this reply before. But it wont work on my case.